# Bluemix CLI command to build docker container image not working

Tags: ibm-cloud, dockerfile

I am trying to build docker image from a dockerfile. When I issue the below command nothing happens in command prompt or in bluemix catalog:

```
bx ic build -t registry.XXXXXXX.bluemix.net/namespace/my_image:v1 dockerfile
```

There is no error log or system hanging.Just returns to next line.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Describe what is meant with "nothing". Does it just hang? Any logs?

Comment: There is no error log or system hanging.Just returns to next line.

Comment: Try to enable trace: `BLUEMIX_TRACE=true` needs to be set.

Comment: could you please add your Dockerfile as well?